# Reversing a generic doubly-linked list in C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to give my generic list class a reverse function. For some reason, my algorithm ain't workin' when I test it. I thought it made sense: swap the pointers to the first and last nodes of the list, then go through the list and for each node swap its pointers to the previous and next node.

Go easy on me, guys. I'm trying to get some practice with generic programming. Teach me the ways of a C++ purist.

Here's the swap function:

```
template <class T> void swap(T* a, T* b) { 
T* tempPtr = a;
a = b;
b = tempPtr;
}
```

Here's the reverse function:

```
template <class T> void List<T>::reverse() { 
    if (size > 1) { 
        swap(firstNodePtr, lastNodePtr);
        node* curNodePtr = firstNodePtr;
        while (curNodePtr != NULL) {
            swap(curNodePtr->prevNodePtr, curNodePtr->nextNodePtr);
            curNodePtr = curNodePtr->nextNodePtr;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the class, its members and prototypes for functions:

```
template <class T> class List { 

public: 
    List();
    ~List();
    void push_back(T);
    void push_front(T); 
    T get_at(unsigned);
    unsigned get_size();
    void reverse();

private:
    struct node { 
        T val;
        node* prevNodePtr;
        node* nextNodePtr;
    };
    node* firstNodePtr;
    node* lastNodePtr;
    unsigned size;

};
```

Comment: An alternative method is to create a new list by "pushing" the nodes in the order you "pop" them.  Then make old head pointer point to new list.

Answer (score 2):

Your `swap<T>` function does not work: it exchanges pointers, which are copied by value into local variables of your function, which has no effect in the caller.

Dropping your own `swap` and replacing it with [`std::swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) will fix this problem.

Comment: I thought that passing in pointers didn't create local copies.

Comment: @user3178285 This is indeed a little confusing: it does not create local copies of the objects to which the pointers point, but it creates local copies of the pointers themselves.

Comment: When I want to modify an array, I've always done foo(int* arr, int n) and that has worked.

Comment: @user3178285 That is true as well - when you pass an array to a function, the compiler transforms it to a pointer for you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you pass the two pointers by value, the changes to `a` and `b` don't propagate out of the  `swap()` function, making it a no-op.

One way to fix it is by passing the pointers by reference:

```
template <class T> void swap(T*& a, T*& b) {
```

Alternatively (and preferably) just use `std::swap()` instead of your own function.

Comment: Or, better yet, use `std::swap` in `<utility>` which will do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you exposed your `node` structure (or at least a bidirectional iterator type for your list), you could avoid the whole issue and just use `std::reverse`.

```
List<int> someList;
// fill with data
std::reverse(someList.begin(), someList.end()); // where begin returns a bidirectional iterator for the head, and end returns a bidirectional iterator for 1 element beyond the tail
```